# Запись в файл все время работы компьютера

Tags: c#

Как на C# написать такую прогу, чтоб она все время работы компьютера записывала текущее системное время и все время в одну строку, то есть постоянно меняла бы значение последней строки?

Не могу понять как именно программу организовать, чтобы консоли не было, и чтобы этот цикл именно не все время с новой строчки записывал время, а заменял всегда последнюю строку.

Вот код, который уже есть, он записывает в файл время включения (Если убрать пустой `while(true)`:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Logs{
    class DoingLogs{
        static void Main(string[] args) {

            DateTime switchTime = DateTime.Now;
            String path = "D:\\client\\file.txt";
            StreamReader readertext = new StreamReader(path);                

            String abc = readertext.ReadToEnd();
            readertext.Close();
            StreamWriter writertext = new StreamWriter(path);
            writertext.Write(abc);
            writertext.WriteLine("Был включен: " + switchTime);

           while (true) {
                //Но что тут писать, я так и не понял 
           }

            writertext.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Если в файле должна быть только одна строка, то можно его сразу открывать на запись, делая truncate

Comment: DeKaNszn, в том и дело, в файле должны чередоваться дата включения и выключения. Добавил имеющуюся прогу в авторан и все работает :) Осталось с выключением разобраться.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Должно работать, консоль исчезает чразу после включения, но необходимо предусмотреть выход из программы

Лог ведется каждую минуту, время можно регулировать в таймере

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

namespace timer
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

        const int SW_HIDE = 0;
        const int SW_SHOW = 5;

        static private String _original_file;
        static private string _path;


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var handle = GetConsoleWindow();
            ShowWindow(handle, SW_HIDE);

            DateTime switchTime = DateTime.Now;
            _path = "D:\\client\\file.txt";

            StreamReader readertext = new StreamReader(_path);
            _original_file = readertext.ReadToEnd();
            readertext.Close();

            StreamWriter writertext = new StreamWriter(_path);
            writertext.Write(_original_file);
            writertext.WriteLine("Был включен: " + switchTime);
            writertext.Close();

            readertext = new StreamReader(_path);
            _original_file = readertext.ReadToEnd();
            readertext.Close();

            Timer t = new Timer(TimerCallback, null, 0, 60000);

            while (true)
            {

            }
        }

        public static void TimerCallback(object o)
        {
            using (var stream = new FileStream(_path, FileMode.Truncate))
            {
                using (StreamWriter writertext = new StreamWriter(stream))
                {
                    writertext.Write(_original_file);
                    writertext.WriteLine("Был изменен: " + DateTime.Now);
                }
            }

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: WinApi тут лишнее.

Comment: Вопрос был: "как организовать, что бы консоли не было", это самый верный способ :)

Comment: @ИгорьВисков верный способ - это открыть свойства проекта и там на вкладке Application поменять Output Type с Console Applicaton на Windows Application. Эти два типа отличаются **только** наличием консоли на старте. а прятать консоль через винапи - это извращение.

Comment: @ИгорьВисков и еще - пустой while (true) в вашем коде будет постоянно грузить одно ядро.

Comment: Несомненно, но это лишь пример, а не готовое решение

Comment: Это ужасный пример. На кой черт создавать отдельный поток таймера - когда основному потоку нечего делать? `Thread.Sleep` тут бы подошел больше.

Comment: Спасибо всем огромное :)
А для выхода из проги перехватываю WM_ENDSESSION